# Why does this return "You still owe: None"

Tags: python

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return nights * 140

bill = hotel_cost(5)

def add_monthly_interest(balance):
    balance * (1 + (0.15 / 12))

def make_payment(payment, balance): 
    new_balance = add_monthly_interest(balance)
    print "You still owe: " + str(new_balance)

make_payment(100,hotel_cost(5))
```

This is printing "You still owe: None" and I feel like I am just missing something very basic.  I am about as new as it could possibly get.  Python is my first language, no other real computer knowledge beyond being as technologically literate as most in my generation.

Comment: Apart from the missing `return`, you may also want `balance * math.pow(1.15, 1.0/12)` rather than `balance * (1 + 0.15/12)` if you want the monthly interest to be the same as 15% over the year. Your way of adding interest gives ~16.1% interest over the year because it's compounded.

Answer (score 5):

`add_monthly_interest` doesn't return anything, so Python has it return `None` automatically. You have to return the result of your expression:

```
def add_monthly_interest(balance):
    return balance * (1 + (0.15 / 12))
```

Answer (score 2):

`add_monthly_interest` needs a return statement.

Answer (score 2):

A function with no return statement (or actually, where execution falls off the end) returns `None`. This is what happens in:

```
new_balance = add_monthly_interest(balance)
```

And so, you get `None`, and you print it. You want a `return` in that function - python does not return the value of the last expression evaluated, unlike some other languages.